# How can I capture traffic to localhost using Wireshark?

Tags: windows-vista, localhost, wireshark, capture

I am using Wireshark on Windows Vista and I would like to capture http traffic to localhost (127.0.0.1), for debugging purposes, but I have some questions.

- How can I do this?
- What capture interface should I use?

  - If I use my NIC as capture interface, only packets to and from the internet are captured.
- Are there any settings in Wireshark to capture packets going to and from localhost?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is, on Windows you can't.  The [Wireshark Wiki](http://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/Loopback) describes a couple of workarounds, such as installing a virtual network card using the Microsoft Loopback Adapter, however the results are less than optimal.  Their suggestion of setting up a new route will give you all of your data twice, and could put unnecessary load on your network if left enabled, but you should get the data.

Comment: This was true in 2010, but Wireshark has shipped with Npcap for a while now and can capture loopback traffic just fine.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reading this in 2019 or later, Wireshark 3.0 ships with [Npcap](https://nmap.org/npcap/), which allows loopback capture.

Answer (score 2):

If you capture on the local loopback interface (called `lo0` on my machine), that will show you the traffic between localhost and itself. The loopback is where localhost traffic goes when it doesn't have to go through the NIC interface.

Comment: Thanks, but I forgot to write that I'm using it on Windows. I have updated my question now.

Comment: Oh okay. I've never actually tried Wireshark on Windows, only Linux and Mac OS X.